# How to print the custom attribute value?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using an input box with type checkbox to check each row and submit the values, and the input field code is like,

```
<input type="checkbox" name="feegroupid[]" data-feeamount="<?php echo $feetype_balance ?>" value="<?php echo $fee_value->fee_groups_feetype_id ?>">
```

Here I have passed a custom attribute called data-feeamount and I need to retrieve the values inside this `data-feeamount`.

I have used the following to print the values and everything works fine except the feeamount,

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    echo "Feeamount: " . $_POST['data-feeamount'];
      if(!empty($_POST['feegroupid'])) {
        foreach($_POST['feegroupid'] as $selected) {
          $test = $selected;
         }
      }
   }
```

While submit I am calling the above function and all the lines are working fine except the line `echo "Feeamount: " . $_POST['data-feeamount'];`.

As I passed the custom attribute I need help in retrieving the custom attribute value.

Comment: You can not get custom attribute value in php in post. you have to use hidden field for store value.

Comment: I am new in php, kindly let me know how to do it?

Comment: How are you sending `data-feeamount` when you are submitting? Can you show that part?

Comment: I am using ```<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Pay">``` and submitting the values, name attribute values are coming but ```data-feeamount``` alone not coming..

Answer (score 0):

From the HTML form is only sent the `value` of given `name` form item.
So in this case the PHP script will receive `$_POST['feegroupid']` as an array (because of `[]` in the element name.  All other attributes are there only because of the `DOM` that is used by javascript for exaple.

If you need to receive other information you can extend the array received:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="feegroupid[<?php echo $feetype_balance ?>][]" data-feeamount="<?php echo $feetype_balance ?>" value="<?php echo $fee_value->fee_groups_feetype_id ?>">
```

And then access it via the multidimensional array:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) and isset($_POST['feegroupid'])){
  if(!empty($_POST['feegroupid'])) {
    foreach($_POST['feegroupid'] as $feeamount => $selected) {
      echo "Feeamount: " .$feeamount . " with value ". $selected
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Data Attributes are used by JavaScript and handled by client-side code.  The value attribute is submitted by the browser and accessible by PHP.

You can make the value attribute an array or use the pipe symbol to send more than one value.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="feegroupid[]" value="<?php echo $feetype_balance ?>|<?php echo $fee_value->fee_groups_feetype_id ?>">
```

You can use a hidden field.

```
 <input type="hidden" name="feeamount" value="<?php echo $feetype_balance ?>">
```

Or you could also use an array and put the array in the value field.